# Foreach in a variable

Tags: php

I have this PHP snippet:

```
<?php 
    $imageresults = get_image_big($string);
    foreach ($imageresults as $hasil) { ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $hasil['media']; ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
```

I would like to output the result in a variable, but it does not work...
I tried:

```
<?php

function bigimgx() {
    $imageresults = get_image_big($string);
    foreach ($imageresults as $hasil) { 
        echo "<img src=\"" . $hasil['media'] . "\" />";
    };
};

$result = bigimgx();
?>
```

Any idea where my error might be? Thank you.

Comment: You have to `return` a value from the function, not `echo` it. Have a look at the PHP manual to learn more about functions: http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you're just `echo`ing the results inside the loop. You need to `return` it instead. Initialize a variable for storing the HTML content, loop through your array and append the HTML to the variable and `return` it after the loop execution is over.

Something like:

```
function bigimgx() {
    $imageresults = get_image_big($string);
    $media = '';

    foreach ($imageresults as $hasil) { 
        $media .= "<img src=\"" . $hasil['media'] . "\" />";
    }

    return $media; 
}

$result = bigimgx();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a string and append the text every loop.  Then return that string, not echo it.

```
function bigimgx() {
    $imageresults = get_image_big($string);
    $return='';
    foreach ($imageresults as $hasil) { 

        $return.= "<img src=\"" . $hasil['media'] . "\" />";
    }
    return $return;
};
```